# Iterating in Slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iteration, slim-lang

say I have an array of strings

```
array = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"]
```

I need to create a Slim structure such as this:

```
      li
        a href="#slide1"
          -puts "one"
          -puts "two"
          -puts "three"
          -puts "four"
          -puts "five"

      li
        a href="#slide2"
          -puts "six"
          -puts "seven"
          -puts "eight"
          -puts "nine"
          -puts "ten"
```

The problem I'm having is creating an iteration in which the first five strings in the array are put under '#slide1' and then once six hits, a new li is creating and the remaining array strings are housed under '#slide2'.

Can this be down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
- array.each_slice(5).each_with_index do |slice, i|
  li
    a href="#slide#{i + 1}"
    - slice.each do |item|
      = item
```

- [`Enumeration#each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)
- [`Enumeration#each_with_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)